# Replicate db_datareader permissions for connecting to Azure SQL from external javascript

Tags: azure, t-sql, google-apps-script

I am trying to tighten up security on connecting to our Azure SQL database by creating custom roles and users, depending on what access to the database is needed. Most of our connections are done via Google Apps Script and have previously used the admin login.

I know it is good practice to not use the db_datareader / db_datawriter roles, but I'm having connection issues whenever I use a custom roles/ users and our **scripts**. The custom user accounts / roles work fine in SSMS but when I use our Google Apps Script I get:

`Connection URL is malformed`

I know the account is authenticating because if I use the wrong password I get a different error. Additionally, the script still works fine with the original database admin account and a **test account I made assigned to db_datareader role**. Accounts with db_datawriter roles work fine as well. So I believe this error message has nothing to do with the actual connection URL.

There seems to be some permission granted by db_datareader / db_datawriter that allows for external scripts to connect and run and I am unsure how to replicate that. Perhaps something that to do with querying a list of the tables that the account /role has access to?

Here is a screenshot of the custom role's permissions, I have omitted database and table names, but these are all on the same database and differing tables and scalar functions that the script needs:

[new role permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic6Ui.png)

Any idea of what I can try to replicate these 'built-in' roles?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your custom role resides in database scope (Expand DB in SSMS -> Security...)
2. Ensure your user is an assignee of the role
3. Check your connection string references a database name
4. Set the default database for the user from the user properties pane

To get the permissions of a role you could use one of the scripts in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role).

Comment: Thank you for responding.
1. It is indeed in the db scope.
2. User is an assignee of the role (verified via script)
3. No change on string and it does reference the database explicitly.
4. This is not an option for me (b/c Azure?) and the code ```ALTER LOGIN [my_user_name] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [new_default_database]``` does not work with the error ```Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
Keyword or statement option 'default_database' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Comment: If the issue is being caused by lack of permissions as opposed to it being a login issue, you're going to need to use profiler to capture the T-SQL being run by the script.  You can filter the capture by login name and it's likely one of the last statement captured that is failing.  Login with SSMS using the new user account and try executing the captured statements against the database to see if any fail.  If you find one that does, SSMS should give you a clue as to which permission is missing.

Comment: If you've not used Azure SQL Profiler, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-ver15